# setting components' locale is unsuccessful

Tags: java, swing, locale, jcomponent

I need my application to set programmatically a locale of all the sensitive components, like `JTextFields` and `JTextAreas`. Also I have date information (month written as a word) which is locale-sensitive too.

I wrote the following code, but it doesn't seem to do the job:

```
    public static void setLocale(java.awt.Container c /* main form */, Locale locale /* Locale.ENGLISH */) {

        Component[] components = c.getComponents();

        for (Component comp : components) {
            if (comp instanceof java.awt.Container)
                setLocale((java.awt.Container) comp, locale);
            comp.setLocale(locale);    
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the failure you're seeing?  Do you get errors?  Does it work on some of the components and not the others?  Does it fail entirely?  Are you sure you're passing a valid Locale?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick:

```
public void switchDefaultLocale(Locale l) {
    if (! l.equals(Locale.getDefault())) {
        Locale.setDefault(l);
        JComponent.setDefaultLocale(l);
    }
}
```

But this will have an effect only on new instance of JComponent.
If you want to update existing instances, don't forget to call updateUI() on each.

Comment: this one doesn't work for some reason... i did JComponent.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); and ive ran updateUI on 4 of my textfields and 1 textarea... no effect

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I don't see a reason to change the locale of
all components in the component tree. [Since](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Component.java#Component.getLocale%28%29) the method
getLocale() automatically searches its parents.

```
/**
 * Gets the locale of this component.
 * @return this component's locale; if this component does not
 *          have a locale, the locale of its parent is returned
 */
public Locale getLocale();
```

So it should be enough to set the locale of the
root of the tree. But whether the locale is respected
somewhere, I can't tell right now.

Bye